# HTML drop down menu going from left to right instead of straight down. display:block not working

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the teams navbar, instead of the listed teams appearing directly beneath it vertically, it goes 1 down then displays it from left to right and I'm not sure why because under  nav ul li:hover > ul I put display:block which in theory should work

```css
nav ul {
  /*Manages locations of the nav boxes*/
  display: block;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  /*Orders the nav boxes from left to right*/
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  /* All the boxes like News, Table etc*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  font: 95% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #66ff66;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="panel center">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <!--All the pages on the website-->
      <li><a href="SerieA_Tables.html">Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Juventus</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">AC Milan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Torino</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `nav ul ul` is the problem take it out and see if anything changes?

Comment: It doesn't fix. It just expands the team column to the same length of the 3 sub-columns and no longer hides them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float:left is causing it on the nav ul li. It's making all li's under the nav be floated left. If you change it to nav>div>ul>li, it'll solve the issue.

```css
nav ul {             /*Manages locations of the nav boxes*/
display:block;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
padding:0px;

}

nav>div>ul>li {   /*Orders the nav boxes from left to right*/
float:left;
}

nav ul li a {                /* All the boxes like News, Table etc*/
display:inline-block;
padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
background-color: gray;
border:1px solid black;
display: block;
line-height: 40px;
font: 95%  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
color: #66ff66;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover{ 
opacity: .7;
text-decoration: none;  
display:block;
}

nav ul ul{              
display:none;
position:absolute;  
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{ /*Highlights box when you hover over it*/
display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="panel center">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>                <!--All the pages on the website-->
                <li><a href="SerieA_Tables.html">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "#">Juventus</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">AC Milan</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Torino</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Just did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float:left;` on your `li`s, use `display:inline-block`, but make sure to target only the parent `li`s so that the sub-menu `li`s are still stacking on top of each other.

```css
nav ul {             /*Manages locations of the nav boxes*/
display:block;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
padding:0px;
}

.panel > ul > li {
display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {                /* All the boxes like News, Table etc*/
display:inline-block;
padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
background-color: gray;
border:1px solid black;
display: block;
line-height: 40px;
font: 95%  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
color: #66ff66;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover{ 
opacity: .7;
text-decoration: none;  
display:block;
}

nav ul ul{              
display:none;
position:absolute;  
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{ 
display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="panel center">
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>                <!--All the pages on the website-->
            <li><a href="SerieA_Tables.html">Table</a></li>
            <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Juventus</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">AC Milan</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Torino</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```